# Parse add string to array swift

Tags: arrays, string, swift, parse-platform

My question is this with an example from the parse docs:

You have in parse the column with all kind of types, like string, array, etc.
Now I have the following kind of code:

```html
var gameScore = PFObject(className:"GameScore")
gameScore["score"] = 1337
gameScore["playerName"] = "Sean Plott"
gameScore.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if (success) {
    // The object has been saved.
  } else {
    // There was a problem, check error.description
  }
}
```

Ok now I want to save another score behind the first score: 1337.
So when I retrieve from parse it will look like this: Sean: 1337, 1207.
Or something like that when I retrieve the name and scores. I have in parse it already set to be an array.
So my question is: How do I add a string to an array in parse.
Thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You need "score" to be an Array in your DB. Then in your code, you do this:

```
gameScore.addObject([1337], forKey:"score")
```